# Exclude default logback file

Tags: java, mysql, logback, jboss6.x

My team is developing a telecom realtime application with high calls per second rate. **We are using logback to filter log based on a key-value match (traffic live values**, like Calling Party, and so on). The filtered log file is correctly created, once verified the match from live values and db values, but **we would get rid of default file which is filled with logs when there is no match**. It might happen that a traffic node needs to be monitored for a while before a key-value match takes place, so in the meantime the default could indefinitely increase in size and cause problems to performance and stability of node itself. **What should I do in my logback.xml to avoid generation of default log file?** Is it possible? Any other option to achieve same result?

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property scope="context" name="LOG_LEVEL" value="INFO" />

<appender name="SIFT_LOGGER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="com.ericsson.jee.ngin.services.log.ServiceKeyDiscriminator">

    </discriminator>
    <sift>

        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <prudent>true</prudent>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">                   
                <fileNamePattern>/var/log/tit/logback_${serviceKey}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>    
                <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>${LOG_LEVEL}</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
            </filter>

            <!-- encoders are by default assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
            <encoder>
                <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%thread]  %-5level %logger{36} %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender> 
    </sift>
</appender> 

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are by default assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->

    <encoder>
        <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender> 

<turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DynamicThresholdFilter">
    <key>serviceKey</key>
    <defaultThreshold>DEBUG</defaultThreshold>
    <onHigherOrEqual>ACCEPT</onHigherOrEqual>
    <onLower>ACCEPT</onLower>       

</turboFilter>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT_LOGGER" />              
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

ATTACHMENTS: [FILTERED LOGBACK CLASS](http://www.figurinesportive.com/ericsson/FilteredLogback.java)

The provided FL class is only working for a SK which has a java Discriminator in FL module.

Comment: Could you include your logback **configuration** e.g. the logback.xml or logback.groovy file. Also, if your question would benefit from providing code then perhaps you could include the code inline rather than as an attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to notify to @glitch (and all others interested) the happy conclusion of this issue: I have managed to make the tag expression working was this:

```
<expression>mdc.get("servicekey") == null</expression>
```

Thanks to this expression, I have got the wanted behavior: the default file "*IS_UNDEFINED* is not generated when the key doesn't match with the runtime traffic values.

The reason is because the type of Event in JaninoEventEvaluator is LoggingEvent that has a reserve object "mdc" (the type is Map).

Regards,
Pierluigi

Answer (score 3):

You must move the filter to the general sift appender.

```
<appender name="SIFT-TRACE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator">
        <Key>loggerFileName</Key>
        <DefaultValue>unknown</DefaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
            <expression>
                mdc.get("loggerFileName")!=null
            </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <sift>
        <appender name="TRACE-${loggerFileName}"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">

            <File>D:/U/${loggerFileName}.log</File>
            <Append>true</Append>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" />

<root level="DEBUG">

    <appender-ref ref="SIFT-TRACE" />
</root>
```

Also to make it work correctly, you MUST after each Thread/file/marker/etc. to put those statements:

```
public void handle()
{
    MDC.put("loggerFileName","some value");
    ...
    MDC.remove("loggerFileName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined this root logger:

```
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT_LOGGER" />              
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

This means that **all** log events with Level >= DEBUG will be directed to two appenders:

- `SIFT_LOGGER`
- `STDOUT`

If I understand your question correctly then you **do** want logs to be written via your `SIFT_APPENDER` but you don't want any other log output. If so, then just remove this entry:

```
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
```

The `STDOUT` appender is a console appender so it doesn't actually write to a log file instead it writes to `System.out`. I suspect the reason you are seeing these log events in *some* file is that whatever is running your application is redirecting `System.out` to a file. As long as you only have your `SIFT_APPENDER` in the root logger definition then you can be confident that this will be the only appender in play. Note: once you remove the appender from the root logger you can probbaly remove it from logback.xml since it is unused.

**Update 1:** Based on your last comment I now understand that you want to discard the logs which arrive at the SiftingAppender but do not match a given condition. I suspect what's happeneing here is that some log events arrive at the sifting appender with an 'unknown' value for `serviceKey` and these events are then written to `/var/log/tit/logback_[unknownValue]_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log`. Is this the crux of the issue? If so, then you can add a filter into the nested appender. Here are some examples:

- Using Groovy to express the 'contains unknown serviceKey condition':

  ```
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
      <!-- GEventEvaluator requires Groovy -->
       <evaluator
          class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator">
         <expression>
           serviceKey == null
         </expression>
       </evaluator>
       <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
       <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
  </filter>
  ```
- Using Janino to express the 'contains unknown serviceKey condition':

  ```
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
       <!-- JaninoEventEvaluator requires Janino -->
       <evaluator
         class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
         <expression>
           serviceKey == null
         </expression>
      </evaluator>
      <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
      <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
  </filter>
  ```

With either of these filters in place any log events which arrive at the sifting appender and have the 'unknown' `serviceKey` will be ignored. Note: I have written the 'contains unknown serviceKey condition' as `serviceKey == null` your logic might differ but the above examples show should you how to tell Logback to apply this filter for you.

Comment: I'm aware that STDOUT is directed to something that in our environment is called **server.log**, where both standard loggings and logback loggings are printed. What this logback.xml generates is a file, named (e.g.) **logback_1_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log** when a incoming call with `servicekey` (this is our key) of value 1 generates a match with values stored into DB. **THIS IS WANTED**. What is **NOT WANTED** is the file that is generated when the `servicekey` doesn't generate a match: in that case a default file is anyway generated to collect every other incoming call. This can be dangerous.

Comment: @Pierluigi I suspect what's happeneing here is that some log events arrive at the sifting appender with an 'unknown' value for serviceKey and these events are then written to `/var/log/tit/logback_[unknownValue]_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log`. Is this the crux of the issue? If so, I have updated my answer with a solution to that.

Comment: Hi, we have extensively test your solution but we still are not able to avoid the default file creation. The default file is created with this name `logback_sk_**serviceKey_IS_UNDEFINED**_2017-09-28_0.log`

Comment: Not sure how to reply to that. I adapted the solution proposed in my answer from a very similar situation on a project I worked on a while back. On that project I was successfully sifting and discarding log events **within the sifter** which did not meet my 'of interest' condition. Sorry to hear you've been unable to get it working.

Comment: So the `[unknownValue]` seems to be **serviceKey_IS_UNDEFINED**. Any tentative to make the <expression> working, failed (`== null, ==*UNDEFINED*, == serviceKey_IS_UNDEFINED`). Do we maybe need to create our own evaluator?